# google-oauth-client-jetty cannot run on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, jetty, google-api-java-client

When I am using Google OAuth2, I need to use the library

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when I try run my webapp on Tomcat 7, the server cannot start and complain the following error:

Oct 14, 2017 9:26:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

What is the reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution at some point?

Comment: I also have the same problem while trying to follow google's the java quickstart tutorial in my webapp. @tapforter his answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

Seems there is a conflict of `servlet-api`. To avoid this you should exclude `servlet-api` from jetty dependency.

On Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
  <version>1.23.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>org.mortbay.jetty</artifactId>
      <groupId>servlet-api</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

On Gradle:

```
compile("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0") {
  exclude group: 'org.mortbay.jetty', module: 'servlet-api'
}
```